# Error Installing Spree in a Rails Project

Tags: spree

I get the error below when trying to install Spree within a new Rails project.  I have Rails version 4.2.5 installed, and Ruby version 2.3.0p0

```
$ spree install --auto-accept
[WARNING] Spree CMD Installer is deprecated. Please follow installation     instructions at https://github.com/spree/spree#getting-started
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-    2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing':     undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x3fcb12418c74     activesupport-5.0.0.1> (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/string.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.1.1/lib/spree_cmd/installer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.1.1/lib/spree_cmd.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spree_cmd-3.1.1/bin/spree:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/spree:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/spree:23:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'`
```

Comment: Mention spree version

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you want to use `spree 3.1` then it

```
 Required rails rails (~> 4.2.6)
```

I have tested spree `3.0 stable with 4.2.2` it might work with your version so to create app with that you can follow https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/3-0-stable

Answer (score 0):

as per the first line of logs

```
Spree CMD Installer is deprecated. Please follow installation     instructions at https://github.com/spree/spree#getting-started
```

which means ..

```
$ spree install --auto-accept
```

wont work..!!

Upgrade rails to 4.2.6 and then follow the steps.

Add Spree gems to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Run `bundle install`

Use the install generators to set up Spree:

```
rails g spree:install --user_class=Spree::User
rails g spree:auth:install
rails g spree_gateway:install
```

and finally

```
rails g spree:install
```